# =ALL(False condition in WHERE clause)

Tags: sql

Let there be a table Tab1

```
Create table Tab1 (
Names Varchar2(40) , 
Sal Decimal (18,2)
                   );
Insert into Tab1 values 
(‘A’ , 1000);
 Insert into Tab1 values 
(‘B’ , 1500);
Insert into Tab1 values 
(‘C’ , 1200);
Insert into Tab1 values 
(‘D’ , 2000);
```

**Problem statement:**

```
Select * From Tab1 where 
Sal = ALL (Select sal
From Tab1 where Sal = 3000)
```

**Output:**

```
All rows from Tab1 came as output
```

**My understanding :**

If sub query returns 0 values then main query should also return 0 values but in this case it’s returning all rows when WHERE statement in subquery holds FALSE.
Though it works fine when it’s TRUE but I cannot understand why it’s throwing all rows when FALSE

Answer (score 4):

Your subquery yields an empty table.  Your ALL clause constitutes a universal quantification.  Mathematically, a universal quantification over an empty set always yields TRUE (because there is no member in the set -no row in the table- that makes it FALSE).

So contrary to your expectation, you are just doing WHERE TRUE instead of WHERE FALSE.

SQL should be expected to expose precisely this behaviour.  I've been trying to find formal confirmation, but unsuccesful so far.  Nonetheless this is probably the reason.

EDIT

Found the relevant section in the standard : 8,9, "quantified comparison predicate".  (Note that this is a different concept than the aggregate operators such as AVG, SUM, ANY/SOME and EVERY.)

"1) Let R be the result of the <row value predicand> and let T be the result of the <table subquery>.
2) The result of “R <comp op> <quantifier> T” is derived by the application of the implied <comparison predicate> “R <comp op> RT” to every row RT in T.
Case:
a) **If T is empty or** if the implied <comparison predicate> is True for every row RT in T, then “R <comp op> <all> T” is True."

Comment: I think this might be formal confirmation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html

Answer (score 3):

This is documented. See [Comparison conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52107)

> If a subquery returns zero rows, the condition evaluates to TRUE.

so - all rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the other answers, `all` returns true when the subquery returns no rows.  You can do one of three things.

Because you have equality, you can use `in` instead of `=`:

```
Select *
From Tab1 
where Sal in (Select sal
              From Tab1
              where Sal = 3000
             );
```

Or use aggregation:

```
Select *
From Tab1 
where Sal = (Select max(sal)
             From Tab1
             where Sal = 3000
            );
```

Or, just dispense with the subquery at all:

```
Select *
From Tab1 
where Sal = 3000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal quantifier is the concept that you should be looking for.

Comment: That's what the Answer by Erwin Smout is already saying.. with explanation.